# How to create pandas column based on condition of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to create a new column `SURV` in the `clin` dataframe based on `clin["days_to_death"]` values, whereby:

- 'lts' if NA or more than or equal to 2*365
- 'non-lts' if condition not met (i.e., less than 2*365)

My code below labeled all the values as 'lts', even when less than 2*365.

`clin` dataframe:

```
clin = pd.DataFrame([[1, '45', '44', 1, nan],
        [1, '121', '68', 0, nan],
        [1, '466', '47', 0, '90'],
        [1, '357', '54', 1, '80'],
        [1, '108', '72', 1, '60'],
        [1, '254', '51', 0, '80'],
        [1, '138', '78', 1, '80'],
        [0, nan, '67', 0, '60'],
        [0, nan, '61', 0, '80'],
        [0, nan, '60', 0, '100'],
        [0, nan, '23', 1, '80'],
        [0, nan, '45', 1, '80'],
        [1, '83', '75', 1, '60'],
        [1, '114', '58', 0, nan],
        [0, nan, '45', 1, '100'],
        [0, nan, '63', 0, '40'],
        [1, '159', '64', 1, '80'],
        [0, nan, '64', 0, '40'],
        [0, nan, '65', 0, '80'],
        [0, nan, '53', 1, nan],
        [0, nan, '58', 1, nan],
        [0, nan, '76', 0, '100'],
        [0, nan, '60', 0, nan],
        [0, nan, '21', 1, '90'],
        [1, '57', '78', 1, nan],
        [1, '95', '79', 0, nan],
        [1, '78', '53', 1, '60'],
        [1, '444', '64', 0, '70'],
        [0, nan, '30', 1, '100'],
        [1, '454', '60', 1, nan],
        [1, '98', '56', 1, '80'],
        [1, '62', '59', 0, '80'],
        [1, '460', '49', 0, '100'],
        [1, '364', '70', 0, '60'],
        [1, '29', '49', 0, nan],
        [1, '88', '60', 0, '40'],
        [1, '485', '60', 1, '60'],
        [1, '42', '52', 0, '80'],
        [1, '975', '58', 1, '80'],
        [0, nan, '57', 1, '80'],
        [0, nan, '36', 0, nan],
        [1, '202', '47', 1, '40'],
        [1, '523', '52', 1, '100'],
        [1, '244', '76', 1, '80'],
        [1, '575', '62', 0, '60'],
        [1, '144', '58', 0, nan],
        [1, '368', '72', 1, '60'],
        [1, '54', '83', 0, nan],
        [1, '684', '53', 1, '80'],
        [1, '428', '56', 0, '80'],
        [1, '511', '77', 1, '80'],
        [1, '455', '56', 0, '80'],
        [0, nan, '39', 0, nan],
        [0, nan, '40', 0, '100'],
        [0, nan, '74', 0, '60'],
        [1, '270', '72', 1, nan],
        [1, '577', '78', 1, nan],
        [0, nan, '47', 0, nan],
        [1, '593', '69', 1, nan],
        [1, '36', '72', 0, nan],
        [1, '585', '66', 0, nan],
        [1, '460', '59', 1, nan],
        [1, '379', '73', 1, nan],
        [0, nan, '61', 0, nan],
        [0, nan, '69', 0, nan],
        [0, nan, '54', 1, '70'],
        [1, '105', '67', 0, '100'],
        [0, nan, '73', 1, '70'],
        [0, nan, '51', 0, '90'],
        [0, nan, '58', 0, '100'],
        [0, nan, '77', 0, '100'],
        [0, nan, '55', 1, '80'],
        [1, '146', '76', 0, '100'],
        [1, '138', '68', 0, '80'],
        [1, '535', '58', 0, '80'],
        [1, '94', '85', 1, '80'],
        [1, '111', '76', 1, '80'],
        [1, '279', '70', 1, '80'],
        [1, '1458', '50', 1, '80'],
        [1, '77', '66', 1, '80'],
        [1, '1121', '52', 1, '80'],
        [1, '508', '57', 0, '80'],
        [1, '100', '74', 0, '80'],
        [1, '82', '78', 0, '60'],
        [1, '519', '63', 0, '80'],
        [1, '254', '64', 1, '80'],
        [1, '638', '60', 0, '80'],
        [1, '147', '66', 0, '60'],
        [1, '153', '74', 0, '80'],
        [1, '727', '54', 0, '60'],
        [1, '1048', '58', 0, '80'],
        [1, '567', '44', 1, '80'],
        [0, nan, '49', 1, '80'],
        [1, '180', '68', 0, nan],
        [1, '191', '72', 1, nan],
        [0, nan, '51', 0, nan],
        [1, '625', '55', 0, nan],
        [1, '1448', '63', 1, '60'],
        [1, '375', '68', 0, nan],
        [1, '399', '65', 0, '100'],
        [1, '317', '62', 0, '80'],
        [1, '225', '72', 1, nan],
        [1, '360', '47', 0, '100'],
        [1, '603', '31', 0, '100'],
        [1, '717', '39', 1, nan],
        [1, '414', '81', 1, nan],
        [0, nan, '49', 1, '100'],
        [1, '164', '58', 0, '80'],
        [1, '3667', '64', 1, nan],
        [1, '224', '76', 1, nan],
        [1, '24', '61', 0, '40'],
        [1, '1537', '21', 0, nan],
        [1, '666', '48', 1, nan],
        [1, '141', '51', 0, '80'],
        [0, nan, '43', 0, '80'],
        [0, nan, '59', 0, '80'],
        [0, nan, '74', 0, '60'],
        [0, nan, '65', 1, '60'],
        [0, nan, '57', 0, '80'],
        [0, nan, '65', 1, '80'],
        [1, '454', '72', 0, '80'],
        [1, '343', '71', 0, '70'],
        [1, '544', '52', 0, '70'],
        [0, nan, '66', 1, nan],
        [0, nan, '42', 0, '100'],
        [0, nan, '72', 0, '80'],
        [1, '713', '53', 0, '70'],
        [1, '335', '62', 1, '90'],
        [0, nan, '52', 0, '80'],
        [1, '157', '63', 0, nan],
        [0, nan, '47', 1, '70'],
        [1, '388', '67', 0, '90'],
        [1, '165', '60', 0, nan],
        [1, '346', '57', 0, '80'],
        [1, '165', '71', 1, '0'],
        [1, '114', '73', 0, '0'],
        [1, '49', '64', 0, '40'],
        [0, nan, '33', 0, nan],
        [0, nan, '50', 1, nan]], columns=['vital_status', 'days_to_death', 'age_at_initial_pathologic_diagnosis',
        'gender', 'karnofsky_performance_score'], index="bcr_patient_barcode")
```

My attempt:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

# Survival info
def survival(clin):
    if np.where(clin["days_to_death"],np.nan,1):
        val = "lts"
    elif clin["days_to_death"].astype(int) >= 2*365:
        val = "lts"
    else:
        val = "non-lts"
    return val


clin['SURV'] = clin.apply(survival, axis=1)
```

Then I want to drop the NAs in all the columns except for the `days_to_death` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create `clin['SURV']` column as you want, you can use `numpy.select` like below:

```
vals = clin['days_to_death'].astype(np.float32)
condlist = [vals>=2*365, vals<2*365]
choicelist = ['Its', 'nonIts']
clin['SURV'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, 'Its')
```

To remove row that contain `np.nan` you can use `dropna(subset=[...])` like below:

```
clin = clin.dropna(subset=['vital_status', 'age_at_initial_pathologic_diagnosis','gender', 'karnofsky_performance_score'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .loc

```
clin.loc[clin["days_to_death"].isna() | (clin["days_to_death"].map(float) >= 2*365), 'SURV'] = 'lts'
clin.loc[clin["SURV"].isna(), 'SURV'] = 'non-lts'
```

Then remove nans

```
clin = clin.dropna(subset=['vital_status', 'age_at_initial_pathologic_diagnosis', 'gender', 'karnofsky_performance_score'])
```